# Weird Shadow effect coming up on CSS Blur

Tags: css, hover, shadow, blur

I have some image blocks, when I hover the block their child image should be blurred and scaled with a small transition effect. It's working perfectly in firefox, but taking in WebKit browsers, there coming up a weird shadow around the edge of the blurred image.

I searched and got a solution in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532270/css-blur-weird-shadow-effect), in there they have answered using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on the element to solve the issue. But when I applied the `translate3d(0, 0, 0)` the shadow is not hidden and it visible like `box-shadow inset` till  on the mouse leave. Check my fiddle and codes below

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/kvfsvaas/)

```
.grid {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    figure {
      margin: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
      -o-transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
      transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
        -o-transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
        transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
        -webkit-filter: blur(0);
        -moz-filter: blur(0);
        filter: blur(0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    &:hover {
      figure {
        opacity: 0.55;
        filter: alpha(opacity=55);
        img {
          -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
          -moz-filter: blur(8px);
          filter: blur(8px);
          -webkit-transform: scale(1.06) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          -moz-transform: scale(1.06) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          -ms-transform: scale(1.06) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          -o-transform: scale(1.06) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(1.06) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is any solution to remove the drop shadow effect in WebKit browsers. Helping would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the **grid** being the background of the **figure**, make it a border around it.

Set the z-index of the **figure** negative, so that it is under the **grid**, and set the margin so that it overlaps the red border, and the bleeding edges are no longer visibles.

Even if you dont't set the negative margins, the effect is much better because now the borders bleed with white instead of red.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.grid {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border: solid 10px red;
}
.grid figure {
  margin: -10px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
.grid figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  transition: all, 0.3s, linear;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.grid:hover figure {
  opacity: 0.55;
}
.grid:hover figure img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  -moz-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
  transform: scale(1.06) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<aside class="grid">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports/1/" alt="">
  </figure>
</aside>
<aside class="grid">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports/2/" alt="">
  </figure>
</aside>
```

Comment: How does it work if avoiding border, because there I want background-color instead of the border for the purpose overlay in the hover.